# How to stream video from LinkedIn to Amazon Fire TV?

Tags: youtube, linkedin, amazon, video-streaming, amazon-prime

How do I stream [videos](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/me/in-progress) from LinkedIn learning to Amazon FireTV?

Notably, YouTube offers to stream to the FireTV device -- at least from my cell phone.  Presumably, there's a mechanism similarly to cast or stream videos from LinkedIn.

similar to:

`Watching Lynda.com Videos from a Television

Note: The Lynda.com Roku app is no longer supported.

You can watch Lynda.com videos on your TV with the Apple TV app, or by utilizing AirPlay, or Chromecast.

The AirPlay button will appear in the bottom right-hand corner of the player window when an Apple TV is detected on the same network. Tap this button and then select your AirPlay device.

The Chromecast button will appear in the top right-hand corner of the player window when a Chromecast device is detected on the same network. Tap this button and then select your Chromecast device, and start watching videos on your TV.`

https://www.linkedin.com/help/lynda/topics/10034/10049/70520/watching-lynda-com-videos-from-a-television?lang=en

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution might be to just log into your LinkedIn Learning account using the Silk browser on your Firestick. Note the site works better with 'request desktop sites' selected, otherwise some navigation options are not accessible.